# How to properly handle important unchecked exceptions

Tags: java, exception, gson

I'm writing a library that wraps around a REST API.  The wrapper I'm creating uses GSON to deserialize the json into my object.  Basically, something like this...

```
public Post getPost(url) throws IOException {
  String jsonString = httpClient.get(url);
  Post p = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Post.class);
  // return Post to client and let client do something with it.
}
```

If I understand correctly, IOException is a checked exception.  I'm telling my client: Hey, buddy - you better watch out and recover from this exception.  Now my client can wrap the call in a try/catch and determine what to do if there is some network failure.

The GSON fromJson() method throws a JsonSyntaxException.  I believe this is unchecked in the Java world, as one of its super classes is RuntimeException, and also because I am not required to add a try/catch or another "throws" like IOException.

Assuming what I have said so far is correct - how exactly should the API and client handle this situation?  If the json string is garbage, my client is going to fail miserably due to the JsonSyntaxException because it's unchecked.

```
// Client
PostService postService = new PostService();
try{
  Post p = postService.getPost(urlString);
  // do something with post
}catch (IOException){
   // handle exception
}
// ok, what about a JsonSyntaxException????
```

What's the best way to handle these situations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are allowed to catch unchecked exceptions. Just add `catch(JsonSyntaxException e)` to your try-catch block. After you catch the `JsonSyntaxException`, you can either handle it or rethrow it as a checked exception.

Ex:

```
try{
    //do whatever
}catch(JsonSyntaxException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    // throw new Exception(e); //checked exception
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is this in the client code? If so, how can the client know that a JsonSyntaxException could be thrown?

Comment: @CodeBlue This could be in the client code (they would know it could be thrown because your API might specify that it could be thrown) or it could be in your `getPost` method. If it's in your `getPost` method you wouldn't catch the `IOException`, you would pass the `JsonSyntaxException` along as a checked exception.

Comment: The question is WHY (seriously: why) are the Json***Exceptions RuntimeExceptions instead of checked Exceptions?!?